# Packaging a REST webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, restful-url

I want to create a REST webservice and want to know if it can be packaged as a jar file. Basically, is it possible that we do not create a war file of this webservice, rather just package as a jar and then put it on Tomcat lib folder?
If that is possible, I would appreciate any help on how to create this kind of webservice; as all the hello-world, examples that i checked on net are packaging as war file only.

Comment: What's wrong with a war file?

Comment: How do you plan on using the JAR?  Typically, the web service you create will expect all incoming requests to hit a servlet which is part of a WAR file.

Comment: WAR is just a JAR with some extras.

Answer (score 0):

For our project which is developing a large scale RESTful web service we use Gradle. You may find the https://spring.io/tools very useful. We find Gradle as a very powerful tool.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking at a webservice as a JAR file, it doesn't make any sense as all your configurations would be ***J2EE*** based. However, if you are aware of JBoss Fuse and OSGI frameworks, that allows you to have bundles as you require.

But I don't think OSGI is an option for you and in simple words, **You cannot package as JAR unless it's OSGI bundles.**

Comment: You can package as JAR if you use WRAP provider (which is by default available in Karaf/JBoss Fuse). I did not downvoted you answer

Comment: @rkosegi Yeah. That's what I meant. We can package as JAR for OSGi. Not sure why it's been downvoted without explanation.